'jwebserver' is not recognized as an internal or external command
I am studying Core Java and my exercise on using jwebserver has hit a blocker.
On my company Windows workstation, I'm using JDK 22. From a working path that I copied from the folder's properties I am using Command Prompt as Administrator with the jwebserver command from what I believe to be the correct folder. I tried:
cd C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\eclipse-workspace\Webserverdemo\src\webserverdemo
The expected result is " URL http:// ipaddress:800/"
The actual result is "'jwebserver' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
I'd be very grateful if anyone could please shed light on this issue? Thank you.

where is JDK22 installed? - use the corresponding path to start it (e.g. "C:\Program Files\JDK22\bin\jwebserver" -- assuming JDK is installed at C:\Program Files\JDK22)

Very good. Thank you for your help!

next step would be adding the complete bin folder path to the PATH environment variable, so that command and all other JDK tools are available without having to type the whole path

Thank you. I have done that now and it's working well.

I added the JDK 22's bin folder to my path by finding the installation directory of my JDK and adding it to my system's path environment variable.
I then used SET command to set the path in my Command prompt. It's working nicely!
